# Returning asynchronous results from inside a node vm, using contextify

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm using contextify ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/contextify ) to run asynchronous 'untrusted' scripts in a node sandbox. The same issue will apply to Node 0.12+ vm.runInContext().

```
Contextify = require('contextify');
rp = require('request-promise');

var myCode = "rp('http://www.google.com').then( function (htmlString) {  RESULT = htmlString })"
defaultContext =  { rp: rp, setTimeout : setTimeout, console: console }

vm = Contextify( defaultContext )
vm.run( myCode );

vm.RESULT
//undefined
```

Are there any undocumented functions, or events that allow me to know when the vm has executed everything?
Or is there a clever way to wrap this request-promise function so that I get a message outside the vm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create an anonymous function to handle the callback to be passed through.

```
Contextify = require('contextify');
rp = require('request-promise');

var myCode = "function(callback) { rp('http://www.google.com').then(callback); }"
defaultContext =  { rp: rp, setTimeout : setTimeout, console: console }

vm = Contextify( defaultContext )
vm.run( myCode )(function(htmlString) {
    // Do what you need here
    });
```

However if you really don't trust the code I would create a secondary anonymous function to protect the callback itself from being possibly modified.

Comment: Thanks @jonathan-gray , it's a good idea. Though part of the trouble is that this myCode, is generating by users.  I'm not sure there is a pattern that could be detected to wrap the function. Can you suggest a way to parse request-promise scripts that could work is most simple use cases? Thanks again

Comment: @LPG What exactly is your use-case that this would not work for? You can simply wrap the user's code such as `"function(callback) {'use strict';\n"+myCode+"\n}"` and anything you pass to it will be shared. For example you can pass a blank object to it. If the object is modified you can retrieve the changes on callback (you can name `callback` something more practical such as `done`).

Comment: The code is very helpful. Specificall I'm dealing with legacy code that couldn't be rewritten. Though I'll suggest a couple changes for future readers. As it is the example fails in contextify, which needs to wrap the function in parens like so: var myCode = "(function(callback) {" + userCode + "})".  Also my use case I would have callback be just marking the job complete. Like so: var myCode = "(x=1;function(callback) { rp('http://www.google.com').then(function(){x=2;callback()}); })" vm = Contextify( defaultContext ) ; vm.run( myCode )(function() { jobIsComplete = true});